# Win application slows down other apps and PC

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have developed a C# windows application in Visual Studio 12. When I run this application, it slows down all other apps and makes PC slow., I think it takes too much of physical memory. Pls suggest some work around to avoid slowing down my PC.
Below is the introduction to application developed : 
The application is very data intensive. The application contains one for loop which loops through around 80000 times and this "for loop" also have one "inner for loop" which loops through 100000 time. I store all the data in lists, arrays and objects(I think these data structures  consuming memory)
 E.X.

```
for(i = 0; i < 80000; i++)
{ 
    for(j = 0; j < 10000; j++)
    { 
         //do some scientific calculations using mathematical formulas (sine, cos          
         //calls some user defined functions 
    } 
}
```

Also suggest how to make this application fast!!!

Comment: What do you do with the data once your 800000000 iterations finish?

Comment: Broadly you could 1) keep less data in memory? stream it in from disk, process a little, save results 2) split input data into smaller batches and run them separately? 3) buy more memory? It's surprisingly cheap (compared to developer time). But that may only be a short-term fix. I think you're really asking if you can use data structures with less overhead to save memory but even if that is possible I think it'd be better to tackle the scale problem as well.

Comment: If your PC has powerful graphic board, try GPU computing. GPU are much powerful than CPU and more parallel executions ara possible by GPU than CPU.

Comment: @Rup thanks for your valuable suggestions, I will follow your first suggestion.

Comment: @Darren Young,,actually I export data to csv file(one row for each "outer for loop" i.e. 80000 rows)

Comment: You may want to look at flushing the data to file at shorter intervals to see if this solves the problem in the first instance.  Are you writing via interop?  If so, how?  Cell by cell?

Comment: @Darren Young ... while the for loop is executing I add data to datatable and at the end I flush data table to csv file..i am not using interop..... Do you think that the problem is because of object or list or array size..

Comment: @user3458895 It's difficult to tell, but worth checking.  If it's a single datatable it won't be over 2GB regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Windows' Resource Monitor to monitor memory usage (and "stand-by" memory consumption => disk cache)? If the priority of your C# application is normal, it seems that your machine depends heavily on that cache so that nearly everything is being slowed down if there is too little free memory that can be used and the "stand-by" region is scaled down.

You should use more fine-grained performance counters to spot the bottleneck.